# Compile-time sanity check provided by role

Tags: perl, moose

I have a module that refuses to load unless a compile-time sanity check is met.  Something like this:

```
package TopSecret;
use Moose;

die "Only Joe can use this!" unless $ENV{USER} eq 'joe';

1;
```

Now I would like to apply a similar sanity check to multiple modules, so my thought is to put it in a role.  The consuming module would provide some information to customize the check a bit.  So it might look something like:

```
package TopSecret;
use Moose;
with 'ForAuthorizedUser';

sub authorized_user { 'joe' }

1;
```

The problem is: how can I exercise TopSecret::authorized_user() from within ForAuthorizedUser, at compile time?  Something like 'requires "authorized_user"' - except it would have to verify not just that the method exists, but execute it and check the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that attribute overriding would be appropriate here. You declare the attribute in your Role and mark it as required, but don't provide a definition. Then the module that consumes the Role can supply the value for that attribute. Note that validation is typically done in the `BUILD()` subroutine.

```
package ForAuthorizedUser;
use Moose::Role;

use Carp qw(croak); # so you can see the line it fails on

has 'authorized_user' => (
   is       => 'ro',
   required => 1,
);

sub BUILD {
   my ($self) = @_;

   croak "Only Joe can use this!" 
      unless $self->authorized_user eq 'joe';
}

1;
```

Now in your module that consumes ForAuthorizedUser, you supply the definition for the attribute:

```
package TopSecret; 
use Moose;
with qw(ForAuthorizedUser);

has '+authorized_user' => (
   default => 'joe',
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

In a separate module you do the same thing, but with a different name (mine):

```
package TopSecret2; 
use Moose;
with qw(ForAuthorizedUser);

has '+authorized_user' => (
   default => 'hunter',
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

Then you could test this like so:

```
use TopSecret; 
use TopSecret2; 

TopSecret->new; # lives
TopSecret2->new # croaks Only Joe can use this! at constructor TopSecret2::new (defined at Test.pm line 35) line 36.
```

Comment: Nice; I like providing a BUILD method in the role.  I don't think this _quite_ solves the whole problem because the sanity check is not exercised until object instantiation, which might not happen (what if a class uses TopSecret but only calls class methods, for example?)  There could be a convention of calling TopSecret->new in any class using TopSecret, but is there a way to get the role to somehow force that?

Comment: I see what you mean. I am not really sure there is a good way to restrict that. #moose on irc.perl.org might have a better idea.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be that you provide a [`before`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod#Before-and-after-Modifiers) method modifier on each of your class methods that checks if the user is authorized.